# WhatsApp only shows contact numbers instead of names on Samsung Galaxy S3

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, samsung-galaxy-s-3

On my Samsung Galaxy S3, the contact names are gone on WhatsApp. All it shows are contact numbers.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure WhatsApp has permissions to allow it to look at your contacts.

Answer (score -1):

Initially you may have added an account in your phone and later changed that account. There can be a problem of sync.

Comment: So how would actually fix this problem? If you don't have an answer to the question this may fit better as a comment.